Using field from QGIS graphical modeller output vector in the same model
I am trying to implement a tool (from a QGIS RStudio script) into my model. The tool takes 2 numerical values as X and Y coordinates and a separate number for the calculation radius. To maximise automation I would like these numbers to vary according to the extent I input at the start of the model.
I calculate the central coordinates of my extent and the radius further back in the model. I have X and Y values as fields in one layer, and the radius as a value in another layer. Both layers only have one feature.
The issue arises when I try to input these values into my tool as a pre-calculated value. For example, I input '@Extract_layer_extent_OUTPUT[CNTX]' for my X coordinate, but after adding a print function to the tool I can see that the script gives X a value of 0.
Is there a different expression I can use to ensure that the value is read correctly?

What is [CNTX]? What if you try x_min (@Extract_layer_extent_OUTPUT)?

[CNTX] is the centre point of x in output of extract layer extent. I used CNTX and CNTY to give me the central coordinates of my extent to apply the radius to later.
I tried x_min (@Extract_layer_extent_OUTPUT) but unfortunately my tool still reads it as 0. I'm wondering if its just something to do with the output file being a temp file..
